# Why is TargetInvocationException treated as uncaught by the IDE?

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, propertyinfo, targetinvocationexception

I have some code that is using reflection to pull property values from an object. In some cases the properties may throw exceptions, because they have null references, etc.

```
object result;
try
{
    result = propertyInfo.GetValue(target, null);

}
catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
{
    result = ex.InnerException.Message;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    result = ex.Message;
}
```

Ultimately the code works correctly, however when I am running under the debugger:

When the property throws an exception, the IDE drops into the debugger as if the exception was uncaught. If I just hit run, the program flows through and the exception comes out as a TargetInvocationException with the real exception in the InnerException property.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This seems to be "by design". What happens is that you likely have menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Debugging* → *General* → *Enable Just My Code* enabled.

As *[How to: Break on User-Unhandled Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/038tzxdw.aspx)* states:

The *Debug* → *Exceptions* dialog shows an additional column (Break when an exception is User-unhandled) when "Enable Just My Code" is on.

Essentially this means that whenever the exception is leaving the boundary of your code (and in this case, it falls through down to the .NET framework reflection code), Visual Studio breaks because it thinks that the exception has left the user code. It doesn't know that it will return into the user code later in the stack.

So there are two workarounds: Disable *Just My Code* in menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Debugging* → *General* ***or*** Remove the check box from the User-unhandled .NET Framework exceptions in menu *Debug* → *Exceptions* dialog.

Comment: Indeed, this helped: I had somewhere a string formatting error (tried to display a TimeSpan in int format, instead of the number of days) and got this error. Inner exception: incorrect format string. But how to find where this formatting was done. When I checked the "Enable just my code" the uncaught exception immediately showed that this was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: I've just tried this myself, and it looks like reflection is treated slightly differently. You might want to think of a reflection call as starting a new level of "handled" as far as the debugger is concerned: nothing is catching that exception before it gets translated and rethrown as a `TargetInvocationException`, so it breaks in. I don't know if there's any way of inhibiting that - but does it happen very often? If you're regularly performing lots of operations which result in exceptions, you might want to reconsider your design.

---

**Original answer**

Go to Debug / Exceptions... and see what the settings are. You'll see this behaviour if `TargetInvocationException` (or anything higher in the hierarchy) has the "Thrown" tickbox checked.

Comment: The use case is a "watch window" for variables that my app is using. To be able to show the user the state of what is going on in the application. So it only happens when the user is requesting the watch window to be updated. At runtime its not really a problem as the exception is ultimately caught, but during development its a huge pain because it keeps breaking me out of running!

Comment: @Jason: Yes, I can see that being a pain. I don't know of a way round it I'm afraid. For most situations it's probably the right behaviour.

Comment: Why would this be the right behavior? If I said to catch it, isn't it caught?

Comment: @Jason: The problem is that you're not really specifying what kind of exception you want caught in the way that you normally would. The translation layer is effectively hidden from you by the fact that you're using reflection. You can't explicitly target one kind of exception being thrown by the caller.

Comment: How is catch(Exception) not catching everything?

Comment: @Jason: You've missed my point: that `catch(Exception)` isn't saying "I want to catch any exception thrown by reflection" - the `TargetInvocationException` is already doing that. The point is that you don't get to say, "I want to catch IOException" when you use reflection; you just have to catch everything by using `TargetInvocationException`.

Comment: A long time passed, but I think you still missed my point. I said catch TargetInvocationException. I said catch Exception. All exceptions, regardless of source, or reflection, or not, should be caught. The IDE behaves as if the exception were uncaught.

Comment: @JasonCoyne: Yes, and my edited answer reflects that.

Comment: @JasonCoyne - You aren't really understanding the problem.  When an exception gets thrown in the property, it is unhandled there, in the property.  The `MethodInfo` invoker (which gets called from `PropertyInfo.GetProperty()` translates the real thrown exception into a TargetInvocationException.  So you're not handling the real exception, you're handling the wrapped exception.  The real exception (which is now wrapped in `TargetInvocationException`) was unhandled.

Comment: If you compile with the 3.5 framework, this does work as expected.