# Reflection MethodInfo.Invoke() catch exceptions from inside the method

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, methods, invoke

I have a call to `MethodInfo.Invoke()` to execute a function through reflection. The call is wrapped in a `try/catch` block but it still won't catch the exception thrown by the function I'm invoking.

I receive the following message:

> Exception was unhandled by the user.

Why does `MethodInfo.Invoke()` prevent the Exception to be caught outside of the `Invoke()`?
How do I bypass it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

EDIT: As I understand your issue, the problem is purely an IDE one; you don't like VS treating the exception thrown by the invocation of the `MethodInfo` as  uncaught, when it clearly isn't. You can read about how to resolve this problem here: [Why is TargetInvocationException treated as uncaught by the IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658908/why-is-targetinvocationexception-treated-as-uncaught-by-the-ide) It appears to be a bug / by design; but one way or another,  decent workarounds are listed in that answer.

As I see it, you have a couple of options:

1. You can use `MethodInfo.Invoke`, catch the `TargetInvocationException` and inspect its `InnerException` property. You will have to workaround the IDE issues as mentioned in that answer.
2. You can create an appropriate `Delegate` out of the `MethodInfo` and invoke that instead. With this technique, the thrown exception will not be wrapped. Additionally, this approach *does* seem to play nicely with the debugger; I don't get any "Uncaught exception" pop-ups.

Here's an example that highlights both approaches:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DelegateApproach();
        MethodInfoApproach();
    }

    static void DelegateApproach()
    {
        try
        {
            Action action = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate
                                   (typeof(Action), GetMethodInfo());
            action();
        }
        catch (NotImplementedException nie)
        {

        }
     }

    static void MethodInfoApproach()
    {
        try
        {
            GetMethodInfo().Invoke(null, new object[0]);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException tie)
        {
            if (tie.InnerException is NotImplementedException)
            {


            }
        }
    }

    static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo()
    {
        return typeof(Program)
                .GetMethod("TestMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    }    

    static void TestMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Am am facing this very issue and in .NET5 it simply does not throw the exception. I tried with VS 2019 16.9.3 and Rider 2020.3. The exception that is being thrown inside the method is a System.Net.Http one. Should I add the necessary packages in my project to be able to catch that one in particular?

Comment: Update on my comment: the invoked method was an async Task one, so I had to call it with await (Task) method.Invoke(instance, null);

Answer (score 22):

How are you trying to catch the exception? Typically what is thrown from a call to `Invoke()` is a wrapping exception instance of `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException`. The actual exception you're after will be in the `InnerException`.

```
try
{
    method.Invoke(target, params);
}
catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
{
    ex = ex.InnerException; // ex now stores the original exception
}
```

Comment: Short and simple solution !