# How to handle Method Invoker Exception

Tags: c#, exception

```
       this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                { code;
                });
```

This results in exception as

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: '...'.

How to handle this??

Comment: Any callstack to show here? or the actual `code;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InnerException` property of [TargetInvocationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.aspx) contains information you need to investigate (see [Reflection MethodInfo.Invoke() catch exceptions from inside the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117228/c-reflection-methodinfo-invoke-block-exceptions-from-inside-the-method) for sample).

In your case it looks like you are accessing some disposed objects (like closed streams) in your delegate. Not much to do with Invoke itself.