# Why Do Invoked Method Calls Not Treat All Exceptions as Unhandled Exceptions When on .Net 4.0+?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, unhandled-exception, system.reflection

I've noticed that the "Just My Code"/"Break On Unhandled Exeptions" feature of debugging isn't working when dynamically invoking a method using the .net Framework 4.0 or higher.  If I change the project to use the 3.5 framework, it runs just fine.

Given this example Command Line App:

```cs
using System;

namespace InvokeFail
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HandledExceptions();
        }
        public static void HandledExceptions()
        {
            try
            {
                Fail();
            }
            catch (NotImplementedException)
            {
                // handle it amazingly well
            }

            try
            {
                InvokeFail();
            }
            catch (NotImplementedException)
            {
                // handle it amazingly well
            }
        }

        private static void Fail()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static void InvokeFail()
        {
            try
            {
                typeof(Program).GetMethod("Fail", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)
                                      .Invoke(null, null);
            }
            catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException ex)
            {
                throw ex.InnerException;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And these VS Debug Options:

[image: VS Options Debugging Dialog]

[image: VS Debugger Exceptions Window]

Here is a picture of where the debugger stops, and it's call stack:
[image: Debugger No Debuggy]

Comment: An assumption of a bug in the unit test runner should always be last on your list.  You expected the exception to be thrown by the Fail() method.  It wasn't, you've got a bug in your Reflection code which causes a NullReferenceException.  You need BindingFlags.NonPublic for private methods.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thanks for catching that.  When I was creating the sample error I found that bug and fixed it and thought I had updated the SO question.  The question is still valid however.  Running that test sample still has the debugger break in the Fail Method, when called reflectively...

Comment: Hmm, works fine on my machine.  Something else you forgot to update?

Comment: @HansPassant I've converted it to a Console App and updated the question, same issue.  Wondering if it has to do with VS 2013?

Comment: @HansPassant I have finally figured out its a .net 4.0+ issue.  The 3.5 Framework behaves as expected.

Comment: Hmm, very doubtful.  I tested on 4.5.1 just like you did.

Comment: @Daryl - My guess is that you are actually looking at this backwards.  I'm thinking that this was actually a bug in 3.5 that allowed it to work, and they fixed it in 4.0, or maybe not a bug but a just a change in behavior that Reflected calls.  It seems to me that your code actually is unhandled, because the invoker has translate the exception.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Can you convert your comment to an answer and reference this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117228/reflection-methodinfo-invoke-catch-exceptions-from-inside-the-method?  I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Daryl - Go ahead and answer your own question, I don't consider my comment to be authoritative enough to be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was a purposeful change in the .net framework with the 4.0 version going forward.

See here for a [definition of the bug and possible work arounds.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117228/reflection-methodinfo-invoke-catch-exceptions-from-inside-the-method)

This was just a comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831236/) question but it makes sense:

> When an exception gets thrown in the property, it is unhandled there,
>   in the property. The MethodInfo invoker (which gets called from
>   PropertyInfo.GetProperty() translates the real thrown exception into a
>   TargetInvocationException. So you're not handling the real exception,
>   you're handling the wrapped exception.