# c# Getting a row in an excel file throws TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I am making a program to manage different projects for a company, the idea is that you put some info and it writes it into an excel file.

The excel files are names ("FINANZAS - ") + Current Year

The idea is that it detects the current year with DateTime and if the excel file for that year doesnt exists it creates it. This is my code:

```
MyApp = new Excel.Application();
        MyApp.Visible = false;
        if (!File.Exists("FINANZAS - " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".xlsx")) { File.Copy(rutaPlantilla, "FINANZAS ARAINCO - " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".xlsx"); }

        MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Finanzas ARAINCO\Finanzas ARAINCO\bin\Debug\FINANZAS ARAINCO - " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".xlsx");
        MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1];
        lastRow = MySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1;
```

The problem comes when I try changing the date to test it with other years, I tried switching it to 2018 for testing but it throws me a TargetInvocationException on the last row (the one that, ironically, I use to detect the last row on excel)

I dont know if this is caused by something on the excel part of the code or if it has something to do with changing the date manually to 2018

Comment: Show the stack trace for that `TargetInvocationException`.

Comment: Why not have a simple variable 
dim x as int 
x = 2018
and then in your code use X if it is > 0 or use DateTime.Now.Year otherwise?
Also, you should compute the target file name once so you don't end up duplicating the filename string all over the place.

Comment: @EugenePodskal I couldnt catch the exception, I tried with 
try{ ... } 
catch (TargetInvocationException TE)
 but it w as unable to catch it.

Comment: @dgorti I dont see how that would make it still work the next year or in two years time

Comment: @SebastianAraneda Then how do you know that it is thrown? Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218249/how-do-i-enable-visual-studio-2010-to-break-when-a-first-chance-exception-happen - perhaps it happens somewhere else.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Because the program stops and Visual Studio shows me the line with the exception, but I tried "try" and "catch (Exception e)" on the line to get the stacktrace but it doesnt seem to catch it because it crashes on the try part of the code

Comment: @SebastianAraneda Forgot about that one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658908/why-is-targetinvocationexception-treated-as-uncaught-by-the-ide

Comment: Of the solutions listed there I couldn't try neither because I already had disabled Just My Code and the second one is for an older version of Visual Studio (the one with the exceptions dialog) and I didn't know how to apply that on Visual Studio 2005

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag you @EugenePodskal

Comment: Have you tried to just run the application outside the Visual Studio? Make top-level exception handler in `Main` and run the compiled exe from explorer.